# Problems with centering <ul> in <div>

Tags: css

I've looked up on how to center an unordered list and found many solutions. For some reason, I can't get it to work though. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<section id="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
        <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
    </ul>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
#gallery {
    text-align: center;
}

#gallery ul{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery ul li {
    display: block;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    margin: 2.5%;
    float: left;
}
```

EDIT: Screenshot - https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoN4n.jpg

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @VincentBeltman I want to center the unordered list inside the parent section.

Comment: You have to set width to `ul` or remove margin from `li`: http://jsfiddle.net/fh87oe9e/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is centre the list list.

Firstly make your ul as display:block;
Secondly remove your float on li and make them display:inline-block;

As the gallery you had set text-align:center. All inline-block element will center themselves and also always put vertical-align on inline-block as the default I think is set as baseline.

**HTML**

```
<section id="gallery">
<ul>
    <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
    <li style="background-image: url('.....');"></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#gallery {
text-align: center;
width:100%;

    background:blue;
}
#gallery ul{
    display:block;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#gallery ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 2.5%;
}

#gallery ul li {
    background-color:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/erwinli/jwph3gk6/)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, this fixed the problem. Not sure why it didn't work before though. It seemed to work for everyone else. Anyway, Thanks.

Comment: Great. Goodluck mate.